# Unable to load tag handler class for custom tag in Java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, custom-tags

I am working with custom tags in Java and I am getting an error. Let me detail below the files involved:

My tag.tld (path is: \WEB-INF\tlds\tag.tld) has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.1//EN" 
                        "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd">


<taglib>
<tlibversion>0.0</tlibversion>
<jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
<shortname>message</shortname>

<tag>
<description>StringReverseTag</description>
<name>string</name>
<tag-class>mytag.StringReverseTag</tag-class>
<body-content>empty</body-content>
<attribute>
<name>data</name>
<required>true</required>
</attribute>
</tag>
</taglib>
```

ReverseEx.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/tag.tld" prefix="jen" %> 
<jen:string data="EARTH"/>

<html>
<head>
<title>Tag Example</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Helper class:

```
package chap4;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;

public class StringReverseTag extends SimpleTagSupport{
    private String data;
    public void setData(String data) {
    this.data=data;
    }

    @Override
    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException{
        JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();
        StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer(data);
        sb.reverse();
        out.print(sb);
    }
}
```

The error I get is the following:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: file:
>   ...Struts/Struts/build/web/ReverseEx.jsp(10,0) PWC6032: Unable to load
>   tag handler class "mytag.StringReverseTag" for tag "jen:string"
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException:  PWC6032: Unable to load tag
>   handler class "mytag.StringReverseTag" for tag "jen:string"
>   ...Struts/Struts/build/web/ReverseEx.jsp(10,0)
>   ...Struts\Struts\nbproject\build-impl.xml:924: Java returned: 1 BUILD
>   FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any good reason for creating custom tag for just reversing a String?

Comment: Just to understand how custom tags work, Aleksandr, with a simple example.

Comment: Please read a more recent JSP 2.x tutorial, not a decade-old JSP 1.x one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your **tag.tld** file you write:

```
<tag-class>mytag.StringReverseTag</tag-class>
```

this means: your class `StringReverseTag` should be in `myTag` package.
but in your code of `StringReverseTag` i can see that you have `chap4` as package!

to solve your problem just change:

```
<tag-class>mytag.StringReverseTag</tag-class>
```

to

```
<tag-class>chap4.StringReverseTag</tag-class>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much. I was wondering about mytag, wasn't sure what it meant.